# The speed of a synchronous motor is determined by frequency, but how about current?

Tags: speed, electric-machine, synchronous-motor

The speed of a permanent magnet synchronous motor is determined by \$ n = \frac {120f}{p}\$, where f is frequency, n is speed in rpm and p is number of poles.
p is fixed in a motor so changing the frequency changes the speed.

If I have a 4 pole motor and I set the frequency to 50Hz I get 1500rpm.

Does this mean the amplitude of the current does not matter at all?

I know that torque is determined by current and flux per pole but my question is merely about the speed of the motor.

Comment: If the current isn't sufficient to produce torque to overcome the load, the motor fails to rotate at synchronous speed.  That may well mean it vibrates in place, perhaps while experiencing other sorts of undesirable failure as well.

Comment: The *no load* speed of a synchronous motor will be determined by the supply frequency. Its speed on load will be lower.

Comment: @Icy are you thinking of an induction motor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you have to apply power to the motor and you have to apply enough supply voltage to overcome motor losses. Once you do that the motor works synchronously off-load but when mechanical load is applied to the shaft there has to be enough current in the source to be able to supply mechanical power and still overcome the losses in the motor.

As a footnote, synchronous speed means exactly that but as a mechanical load increases, the rotating shaft "slips" a small angle to accommodate that change in load and draw more current.

Comment: Aha, so as long as the motor losses have been overcome it doesn't matter whether you increase the voltage or not, the speed depends on the frequency. Tdeveloped=Tload+Tfriction so increasing load requires a higher Tdeveloped and that is obtained by drawing (automatically) a higher current from the supply, increasing torque reduces speed. Got it thanks